# Divergence of 4-velocity tensor

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

Today my professor told us that in Robertson-Walker metric the divergence of the 4-velocity of the element of the cosmic fluid $u^a_{\,;a}$ can be calculated with:
$$u^a_{\,;a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}(\sqrt{-g}u^a)_{,a}$$
Now I have two questions. How can this relation be proved?
Then, if I have the 4-velocity as $u^a=(1,0,0,0)$, since we are in the frame of the cosmic fluid, the professor said that
$$u^a_{\,;a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}(\sqrt{-g}u^a)_{,a}=\frac{1}{a^3}(a^3)_{,0}=3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$$ where $a$ is the scale factor. Now my other question is: if I evaluate the divergence as
$$u^a_{\,;a}=u^0_{\,;0}+u^1_{\,;1}+u^2_{\,;2}+u^3_{\,;3}$$ I end up with the calculation of $u^0_{\,;0}$ because the 4-velocity is only non zero in the time direction. So I can recall $$v^\mu_{\,;\nu}=v^\mu_{\,,\nu}+\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda}v^\lambda$$
which is zero for $\mu=\nu=0$ according to my calculations. In this way I get a zero value for the divergence of the 4-velocity. Where is my error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Furthermore I really can't understand why the determinant is equal to $a^3$

Answer (score 2):

To start, your first formula

$$u^a{}_{;a} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} (\sqrt{-g}u^a),a = \partial_a u^a + \partial_a (\log\sqrt{-g})\, u^a$$

is a standard one; you can easily derive it if you know that

$$\Gamma^b{}_{ba} = \partial_a \log\sqrt{-g}.$$

Moving on to the rest of your question, the problem is that $u^a{}_{;b}$ or $\nabla_b u^a$ is an abuse of notation. The covariant derivative is not an operator that can be applied to the components of a vector; it takes a whole vector, and results in a tensor. Strictly speaking, its components should be written as

$$(\nabla u)^a{}_b,$$

and the divergence should be

$$(\nabla u)^a{}_a.$$

This is why your equation

$$u^a_{\,;a}=u^0_{\,;0}+u^1_{\,;1}+u^2_{\,;2}+u^3_{\,;3}$$

is not true; the Einstein summation convention doesn't apply directly because again, $u^a{}_{;a}$ is an abuse of notation. Like I said above, $u^0{}_{;0}$ doesn't make sense; you can't take the covariant derivative of a component of a vector.

If you use the first formula, together with the fact that the metric is $g_{ab} = \mathrm{diag}(-1, a^2, a^2, a^2)$ and thus the determinant is $g = -a^6$, you'll get the desired result.

Comment: Ok thanks, now I got the point but I don't understand why $\nabla_b u^a$ is an abuse of notation. On all my textbooks it is defined in this way

Comment: Because now doing all the calculations with $u^a_{\,;a}$ I get the same result as using the formula so I'm really having problem with this. With $u^0_{\,;0}$ I've always meant the covariant derivative along the 0 direction of the 0 component of the 4-velocity.

Comment: In the Hartle book I read: $\nabla_a v^b=\frac{\partial v^b}{\partial x^a} + \Gamma^b_{a c} v^c$ and so I always used this formula for the covariant derivative

Comment: @StefanoManzoni I'm not sure I understand. How would you calculate $u^0{}_{;0}$, for example? I'm asking this so I can improve my answer.

Comment: I'd do this $u^0_{\,;0}=\partial_0 u^0+\Gamma^0_{0\lambda}u^\lambda$ where $\lambda$ must be zero because $u^i=0$. So I end up with $u^0_{\,;0}=0$. Then $u^1_{\,;1}=\partial_1 u^1+\Gamma^1_{10}u^0$ and so on

Comment: Right, but $\Gamma^1{}_{10} \neq 0$. That's where the divergence comes from.

Comment: Yes, this morning I found a mistake in my previous calculations. So I get the same result as my professor. But again, writing the covariant derivative as I do is wrong?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by wrong - it's technically misleading, but it's convenient and everyone does it. I also misunderstood your problem; I thought you were making a mistake expanding the divergence (which is why I mentioned the covariant derivative issue), but that wasn't the problem.